# How can I remove the elements containing False in this list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
list={{(m+1) x^2-5 (m+1) x+(-m-1),False},{(m+1) x^2-5 (m+1) x+(1 m+1),False},{(m+1) x^2-5 (m+1) x+(4 m-5),-5<m<=-1},{(m+1) x^2-4 (m+1) x+(-5 m+4),False},{(m+1) x^2-4 (m+1) x+(-3 m+4),False},{(m+1) x^2-4 (m+1) x+(-m-1),False},{(m+1) x^2-4 (m+1) x+(-m+4),False},{(m+1) x^2-4 (m+1) x+(1 m-5),-3<m<=-1}}
```

I would like to remove elements containing `False` and keep the list:

```
{{(m+1) x^2-5 (m+1) x+(4 m-5),-5<m<=-1},{(m+1) x^2-4 (m+1) x+(1 m-5),-3<m<=-1}}
```

How can I tell Mathematica to do that?

Comment: another common way to do this is `DeleteCases[list, {___, False, ___}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or use Select

```
{
    {(m + 1) x^2 - 5 (m + 1) x + (-m - 1), False}
    ,
    {(m + 1) x^2 - 5 (m + 1) x + (1 m + 1), False}
    ,
    {(m + 1) x^2 - 5 (m + 1) x + (4 m - 5), -5 < m <= -1}
    ,
    {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-5 m + 4), False}
    ,
    {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-3 m + 4), False}
    ,
    {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-m - 1), False}
    ,
    {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-m + 4), False}
    ,
    {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (1 m - 5), -3 < m <= -1}
} // Select[Not @* MemberQ[False]]
```

Answer (score 5):

A one way is to replace them to special symbol called "Nothing"

```
list/. {_, False} :> Nothing
```

Comment: Note that this does not work if `False` was not in last position in the list

Comment: @Nasser Sure, then one can use list /. {{___, False, ___} :> Nothing} or inefficient and dangerous list //. {{any1___, x_List?(! FreeQ[#, False] &), any2___} :> {any1, 
    any2}} acting on all levels, etc... The task is too simple...

Comment: You could just do `list /. {___, False, ___} :> Nothing`  same as with the DeleteCases example. This will take care of removing the list regadless of where `False` was in the list.

Comment: @Nasser For some reason first ___ in the list is not shown in my comment. How do you enter Mma code into comment?

Comment: I use backtick then write the code then put another backtick.  make sure there is no space between the ticks and the code

Answer (score 4):

To also cover cases with `False` in different positions:

```
Delete[List @* First /@ Position[list, False]] @ list
```

returns

```
{{-5 + 4 m - 5 (1 + m) x + (1 + m) x^2, -5 < m <= -1}, 
{ -5 + m - 4 (1 + m) x + (1 + m) x^2, -3 < m <= -1}}
```

Or, with the same result,

```
DeleteCases[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[False, ___]}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{(m + 1) x^2 - 5 (m + 1) x + (-m - 1), 
   False}, {(m + 1) x^2 - 5 (m + 1) x + (1 m + 1), 
   False}, {(m + 1) x^2 - 5 (m + 1) x + (4 m - 5), -5 < 
    m <= -1}, {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-5 m + 4), 
   False}, {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-3 m + 4), 
   False}, {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-m - 1), 
   False}, {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-m + 4), 
   False}, {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (1 m - 5), -3 < m <= -1}}
```

---

```
Select[FreeQ[False]][list]

Select[ContainsNone[{False}]][list]

Pick[list, Map[Count[False]][list], 0]

Pick[list, Counts /@ list // Map[#[False] &], _Missing]

Pick[list, Position[False] /@ list // Map[Length], 0]

Pick[list, # == DeleteCases[#, False] & /@ list]
```

---

*Result:*

```
{{-5 + 4 m - 5 (1 + m) x + (1 + m) x^2, -5 < m <= -1}, {-5 + m - 
   4 (1 + m) x + (1 + m) x^2, -3 < m <= -1}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {
          {(m + 1) x^2 - 5 (m + 1) x + (-m - 1), False}
          ,
          {(m + 1) x^2 - 5 (m + 1) x + (1 m + 1), False}
          ,
          {(m + 1) x^2 - 5 (m + 1) x + (4 m - 5), -5 < m <= -1}
          ,
          {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-5 m + 4), False}
          ,
          {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-3 m + 4), False}
          ,
          {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-m - 1), False}
          ,
          {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (-m + 4), False}
          ,
          {(m + 1) x^2 - 4 (m + 1) x + (1 m - 5), -3 < m <= -1}
      };
```

Using `Cases`:

```
Cases[list, v_ /; FreeQ[v, False]]

(*{{-5 + 4 m - 5 (1 + m) x + (1 + m) x^2, -5 < m <= -1},
   {-5 + m - 4 (1 + m) x + (1 + m) x^2, -3 < m <= -1}}*)
```

Another way using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, MatchQ[Boole@*BooleanQ /@ #, {0 ..}] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{-5 + 4 m - 5 (1 + m) x + (1 + m) x^2, -5 < m <= -1},
   {-5 + m - 4 (1 + m) x + (1 + m) x^2, -3 < m <= -1}}*)
```